# Rxjava 2 on error is not called while unit testing

Tags: android, kotlin, junit

Rxjava 2 on error is not called while unit testing . I am using kotlin with rxJava 2 .

> method

```
  @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    override fun fetchFilms() {
        view.showLoader(true)
        disposable = getRetrofitInstance(false).create(API::class.java)
                .fetchFilms()
                .subscribeOn(io)
                .observeOn(main)
                .subscribeWith(object : DisposableObserver<Response>() {
                    override fun onComplete() {
                    }

                    override fun onNext(t: Response) {
                        println(t)
                        view.setAdapter(t?.results as List<ResultsItem>)
                        view.showLoader(false)
                    }

                    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                        view.showLoader(false)
                        view.showError(e.message.toString())                    }

                })


    }
```

> Test

```
@Test
    fun  fetchInvalidDataShouldThrowError(){

        `when`(api.fetchFilms()).thenReturn(Observable.error(IOException()))
   filmsPresenter.fetchFilms()
        val subscriber = TestSubscriber<Response>()

        subscriber.awaitTerminalEvent(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS)

        verify(filmsView, times(1)).showLoader(true)
        verify(filmsView).showError("t")
        verify(filmsView).showLoader(false)


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your actually creating two `API` here.

every time `fetchFilms()` on presenter gets called a new API is created. you can not mock the `API` in this way.

best guess to fix it is to pass `API` object as a method parameter to `fetchFilms()` in the presenter. this way you can decide to provide a real `API` or a mock one

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're running your code asynchonously in tests as well.

You'd have to *synchronise* the schedulers you use before.

```
@Before
fun setupSchedulers() {
    RxAndroidPlugins.setMainThreadSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
    RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
}

@Test
fun  fetchInvalidDataShouldThrowError() {
    `when`(api.fetchFilms()).thenReturn(Observable.error(IOException("t")))
    filmsPresenter.fetchFilms()

    verify(filmsView).showLoader(true)
    verify(filmsView).showError("t")
    verify(filmsView).showLoader(false)
}
```

Comment: onerror is not getting called , for success test is working fine

Comment: i get this "Wanted but not invoked:" error for verify(filmsView).showError("t")

Comment: like this     @Before
    fun setup() {

        RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler { scheduler -> Schedulers.trampoline() }
        RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler { t -> Schedulers.trampoline() }

Comment: It looks like `filmsPresenter` has properties `io` and `main`. Could you add how you initialize it? Depending on it, it might not even be necessary to setup the plugins...

Answer (score 1):

I had pass repo to Presenter to have same instance API .

> here are some changes i have to make

```
class RepoTest(val api : API) {
    fun filmm() : Observable<Response> {
        return api.fetchFilms()
    }
}
```

> presenter

```
class FlimsPresenter(private val view: GetFlimsContract.View,  repo: RepoTest) : GetFlimsContract.Presenter
```

> method

```
 override fun fetchFilms() {
        view.showLoader(true)
        disposable = repot.filmm()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(object : DisposableObserver<Response>() {
                    override fun onComplete() {
                    }

                    override fun onNext(t: Response) {
                        println(t)
                        view.setAdapter(t?.results as List<ResultsItem>)
                        if (t?.results.isEmpty()) view.showEmptyView(true)
                        else view.showEmptyView(false)
                        view.showLoader(false)
                    }

                    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                        view.showLoader(false)
                        view.showError(e.message.toString())
                    }

                })


    }
```

> Finally test

```
class TestSample {
    @Mock
    private lateinit var filmsPresenter: GetFlimsContract.Presenter


    @Mock
    private lateinit var filmsView: GetFlimsContract.View


    private lateinit var api: API
    @Mock
    private lateinit var disposable: Disposable
    @Mock
    lateinit var repoTest: RepoTest

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        RxAndroidPlugins.setMainThreadSchedulerHandler { scheduler -> Schedulers.trampoline() }
        RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler { scheduler -> Schedulers.trampoline() }
        RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler { t -> Schedulers.trampoline() }
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)

        repoTest = Mockito.mock(RepoTest::class.java)

        filmsView = Mockito.mock(GetFlimsContract.View ::class.java)

        filmsPresenter = FlimsPresenter(filmsView,repoTest )
    }


    @Test
    fun `should lod item into views`() {

        Mockito.`when`(repoTest.filmm()).thenReturn(Observable.just(Response("","",7, listOf(ResultsItem()))))
        filmsPresenter.fetchFilms()

        Mockito.verify(filmsView).showLoader(true)
        Mockito.verify(filmsView).setAdapter(anyList())
        Mockito.verify(filmsView).showLoader(false)
    }


    @Test
    fun `should show error if network call fails`(){

        Mockito.`when`(repoTest.filmm()).thenReturn(Observable.error(Exception("t")))
        filmsPresenter.fetchFilms()
        Mockito.verify(filmsView).showLoader(true)
        Mockito.verify(filmsView).showError("t")
        Mockito.verify(filmsView).showLoader(false)
    }
}
```